# How to write a for loop to look up and replace?

Tags: javascript, loops, mirth

I'm having trouble writing a function to iterate through a list, look up and replace if matched. This is what I have so far:

```
function lookupTests(tests) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) { 
        const currentTest = tests[i];
        // check if the current fruit exists in the lookup table
        if (translation[currentTest]) {
            // replace the current fruit with its value from the lookup table 
            tests[i] = translation[currentTest]; 
        }
    } 
};
    
var translation = {
    'AMIK':'AMIK',
    'GROU':'GPW',
    'AASC':'ABW',
    'ICOO':'ABW',
    'HPLC':'HBEW',
    'SICK':'SICW',
};
```

```
var tests = lookupTests([AASC,GROU]);
```

The error message I am getting is

```
DETAILS:    TypeError: Cannot read property "AASC" from undefined
```

Comment: pass as strings? ['AASC','GROU']

Comment: Please provide a [mre], preferably as a Stack Snippet.

Comment: @cmgchess They must be doing that, since they're not getting an error saying that `AASC` is undefined. So it's a copying error here.

Comment: The error is saying that `translation` is undefined. Are you sure you declared the variable as you show?

Comment: How is Mirth related to this?

Comment: @Barmar - yes everything is declared as above. Its used within Mirth environment

Comment: I don't know anything about Mirth, maybe it's related to the problem?

Comment: I dont think so - it uses native Javascript

Answer (score 0):

The code worked as expected, you just need to add a `return` at the end of your function.

[image: Showing the code used in this instance.]

Comment: OK  - I see the issue, you have used ['AASC','GROU']  but my input is [AASC,GROU] .  This is coming from a text.split(',')  which doesnt add the 's  ( I hope that makes sense. )  How can I add those in. ?  Also - what IDE is this ? @parham

Comment: @grahamie this is browser developer tools. btw if you split `'AASC,GROU'` by `','` it should give `['AASC','GROU']` as an array

Comment: @cmgchess - the split doesnt do that .
takes AASC,GROU
gives [AASC, GROU]

Comment: as @mgchess said this is browser dev tool showing this way, split returns An Array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the answer before works and I wrote something too, I wanted to share this solution: Using Object.entries(), that way you you can have more control over the keys and values of the entry.

```
function lookupTests(tests) {
  // Iterate the translations: 
  // Keys would be 'AMIK', 'GROU' ... e.g. the first part
  // Values would be 'AMIK', 'GPW' ... e.g. the second part
  Object.entries(translation).forEach(([translationKey, translationValue]) => {
  // Iterate the tests:
  // Keys would be 0, 1, 2, 3 ...
  // Values would be the array you provide e.g. ['AASC', 'GROU']
    Object.entries(tests).forEach(([testsKey, testsValue]) => {
      if (translationKey !== testsValue) return
      tests[testsKey] = translationValue
    })
  })
  return tests
}

var translation = {
    'AMIK':'AMIK',
    'GROU':'GPW',
    'AASC':'ABW',
    'ICOO':'ABW',
    'HPLC':'HBEW',
    'SICK':'SICW',
};

var tests = lookupTests(['AASC', 'GROU']);
console.log(tests)  returns  ['ABW', 'GPW']
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks this is nice and clean. I think the issue I am finding is with my .split(',')  function. It isn't assigning the codes as ['AASC','GROU']. It is taking AASC,GROU and formatting it as [AASC,GROU]

Comment: I have gotten around that manually.... 
var newtest = "['" + $('test') + "']"
var newtest = newtest.replace(",","','")